# Encrypt xml file in .net and decrypt in java using x509 certificate

Tags: java, .net, xml, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I spend almost a day searching on web for the following requirement and end with only encryption and decryption done in .net but not on java.

I want to encrypt file in .net and decrypt it on java using x509Certificate

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=CERT_SIGN_TEST_CERT" -b 01/01/2010 -e 01/01/2012 -sky exchange -ss my
```

using this command i generate certificate and exported .pfx file from certificate and this pfx file is used to encrypt the xml file

> in .net using EncryptedXml , X509Certificate2, RSACryptoServiceProvider and 
>   XmlDocument classes (.Net)

i encrypt following xml

```
<Test><Name>Foo</Name><CardNo>123</CardNo></Test>
```

as follows:

```
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" /><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" /><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><X509Data><X509Certificate>MIICFzCCAYCgAwIBAgIQK5IFtxwNaJhGzXuDf92TgzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADAfMR0wGwYDVQQDHhQARgBpAG4AYQBsAF8AQwBlAHIAdDAeFw0wOTEyMzExODMwMDBaFw0xMjEyMzExODMwMDBaMB8xHTAbBgNVBAMeFABGAGkAbgBhAGwAXwBDAGUAcgB0MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC1Wx11luboMbT1swXV/56j2RYRhR81n9hF3b6tfof1zHRorg7DIP3hvnVtqDF+WxAjn1um97DHtxWf3solthbIHC9cGtqxUhZhgdd0aVAuiKTBbTgnOWdEqTErenrHOzlZnD9iDzOm3OYVLKN+3hKJmjlhTp0sFsu4AIbXlxZVHQIDAQABo1QwUjBQBgNVHQEESTBHgBBDXPlnSZ5zUyVbxJzJO12goSEwHzEdMBsGA1UEAx4UAEYAaQBuAGEAbABfAEMAZQByAHSCECuSBbccDWiYRs17g3/dk4MwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQADgYEAiubZJZdF3Y9ItOl7LTyixcbuebs50GLFsTeMslS3usq6psXcUEFJntXJ5vXOSe/vp6E6A5AwW4MtPfnB1kzach4T4+WlWeaDHoyj6y5j+n7P6B/X6ZhkQ8MCiGhZ/fTOt7CDisnFVG9gvoH2LUEs1QkiByDq6jii3TUAMN9YQdA=</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo><CipherData><CipherValue>Vyml+mtbeL5bE6EWKNqHfnE1xEkbJglcxbjH3Y7pj9BtXVImAI/SbBdLHatyjIAei7qUfhcn+qYC7WAh48XR78BgqCdJX7O5lfZjVSVeVaQUwl1Bdirdz7RYuveIjDtEIM80W4tB6rq2nOgYNkisxhhwIl7EiCQtT42bSGCKFic=</CipherValue></CipherData></EncryptedKey></KeyInfo><CipherData><CipherValue>ezVeQlBGZRbHqitB2mmHuMvifGB9IhG1g0CWmL8iz37JIIw7x5cGbb5Ap8iy24ACu8TJpwgAGIUWnUTDSZ//kWLzCa3G5HL+jT/RHn+zypk=</CipherValue></CipherData></EncryptedData>
```

as far as encryption is done using w3c standard. How can i decrypt this xml file on java. I have used .pfx file to encrypt the file. In .net i can decrypt file using following:

```
 EncryptedXml encXml = new EncryptedXml(xmlEncDoc);  
encXml.DecryptDocument();
```

How can i decrypt in java, should i pass pfx file to java end? as there is `<X509Data>` tag in encrypted xml file.

your suggestion is appriciated.